# how is the onListItemClick() method of ListActivity invoked?

Tags: android, listactivity

I am new to programming and wanted to know that how is the **onListItemClick()** method invoked:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){ 
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id)
};
```

My question is that when we click on the list item who calls this method :
is it some kind of System callback,
is DVM responsible for invoking it,
or what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is that when we click on the list item who calls this
>   method : is it some kind of System callback, is DVM responsible for
>   invoking it, or what is it?

`ListActivity` does what you would have done if you were extending `Activity` instead of `ListActivity`. It registers an instance of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`, and when the callback's method is invoked, it calls the method you are overriding.

Answer (score 1):

Android is an open source platform so you can check all classes from SDK to figure how they work.

Checking AbsListView, which is parent of ListView, you will see this method:

```
@Override
public boolean performItemClick(View view, int position, long id) {
    boolean handled = false;
    boolean dispatchItemClick = true;

    if (mChoiceMode != CHOICE_MODE_NONE) {
        handled = true;
        boolean checkedStateChanged = false;

        if (mChoiceMode == CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE ||
                (mChoiceMode == CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL && mChoiceActionMode != null)) {
            boolean checked = !mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            mCheckStates.put(position, checked);
            if (mCheckedIdStates != null && mAdapter.hasStableIds()) {
                if (checked) {
                    mCheckedIdStates.put(mAdapter.getItemId(position), position);
                } else {
                    mCheckedIdStates.delete(mAdapter.getItemId(position));
                }
            }
            if (checked) {
                mCheckedItemCount++;
            } else {
                mCheckedItemCount--;
            }
            if (mChoiceActionMode != null) {
                mMultiChoiceModeCallback.onItemCheckedStateChanged(mChoiceActionMode,
                        position, id, checked);
                dispatchItemClick = false;
            }
            checkedStateChanged = true;
        } else if (mChoiceMode == CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) {
            boolean checked = !mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            if (checked) {
                mCheckStates.clear();
                mCheckStates.put(position, true);
                if (mCheckedIdStates != null && mAdapter.hasStableIds()) {
                    mCheckedIdStates.clear();
                    mCheckedIdStates.put(mAdapter.getItemId(position), position);
                }
                mCheckedItemCount = 1;
            } else if (mCheckStates.size() == 0 || !mCheckStates.valueAt(0)) {
                mCheckedItemCount = 0;
            }
            checkedStateChanged = true;
        }

        if (checkedStateChanged) {
            updateOnScreenCheckedViews();
        }
    }

    if (dispatchItemClick) {
        handled |= super.performItemClick(view, position, id);
    }

    return handled;
}
```

> My question is that when we click on the list item who calls this
>   method : is it some kind of System callback, is DVM responsible for
>   invoking it, or what is it?

Yes. It is some kind of callback.